# Visual Editor Not Working 4.7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-4.7

My WordPress visual editor is not working. I tried all of the solutions on the Google but nothing changed.

- Visual editor is not disabled for me (Checked it from profile page and enabled/disabled for times)
- CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS to false not working.
- WP_DEBUG to true not working.
- Tried with different users not working.
- Disabled all plugins not working.
- Tried with different browser/computer not working.
- No error output on JS Console
- Tried with plain permalink, not working.

I’m really getting crazy with it. I’m using latest WP version and 2017 theme. Any other solutions?

Edit: I checked the Network Tab on the Developer Console, tinymce.min.js file doesn't exist there. It's not loading. Loaded JS Files:

- jquery.js?ver=1.12.4
- jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1
- utils.min.js?ver=4.7
- plupload.full.min.js?ver=2.1.8
- hoverIntent.min.js?ver=1.8.1
- common.min.js?ver=4.7
- admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.7
- heartbeat.min.js?ver=4.7
- autosave.min.js?ver=4.7
- suggest.min.js?ver=1.1-20110113
- wp-ajax-response.min.js?ver=4.7
- wp-ajax-response.min.js?ver=4.7
- jquery.color.min.js?ver=2.1.1
- wp-lists.min.js?ver=4.7
- core.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- sortable.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- postbox.min.js?ver=4.7
- position.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- wp-a11y.min.js?ver=4.7
- autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4
- tags-suggest.min.js?ver=4.7
- tags-box.min.js?ver=4.7
- underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3
- word-count.min.js?ver=4.7
- post.min.js?ver=4.7
- editor-expand.min.js?ver=4.7
- thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105
- shortcode.min.js?ver=4.7
- backbone.min.js?ver=1.2.3
- wp-util.min.js?ver=4.7
- wp-backbone.min.js?ver=4.7
- media-models.min.js?ver=4.7
- wp-plupload.min.js?ver=4.7
- mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=2.22.0
- wp-mediaelement.min.js?ver=4.7
- media-views.min.js?ver=4.7
- media-editor.min.js?ver=4.7
- media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=4.7
- mce-view.min.js?ver=4.7
- jquery.imgareaselect.min.js?ver=4.7
- image-edit.min.js?ver=4.7
- svg-painter.js?ver=4.7
- wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=4.7
- quicktags.min.js?ver=4.7
- wplink.min.js?ver=4.7
- media-upload.min.js?ver=4.7
- wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7
- wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7

Comment: Which visual Editor version do you have used?

Comment: Any answer or solution?

Comment: I haven't any idea about this. Would you please attach screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I found my problem. My wp-tinymce.php file has 777 permission btw server was blocking this file.

My solution was making its permission to 644..

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with no solution so far, but:
when not only deactivating but also deinstalling TineMCE Advanced, everything is working as desired.
Already opened an issue on their wordpress-Plugin page.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with a fresh install of version 1.4.7.
No problem with my updated websites !

**EDIT**

Solution to fix the issue:

1. Copy `/wp-admin/` and `/wp-includes/` folders from an automatic uptdated WordPress website.
2. Replace all these file into your broken website.

If someone want these files, I created [a link here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9trBPDuG70HZDIwMjVBbDI5QTQ).